# Split list into two lists depending on adjacent cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a little help, I have an Excel book with a long list of customers and in the adjacent cell is ether a 1 or 0 depending if the customer has ordered in the past month.

How can I split this list into 2 lists on another page one been ordered in the past month and the other not ordered,

Im unable to use Macros due to security levels on the PC.

Thanks

Comment: Data > Sort on order...Or does it need to be dynamic?

Comment: It needs to be Dynamic and also show in two separate lists

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
'for ones
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B))=1), ROW(1:1)))
'for zeroes
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B))=0), ROW(1:1)))
```

Of course, you will have to modify to suit the different worksheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the image below. Using array formulas (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) I entered this into `D2:D8`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A8,SMALL(IF(B2:B8,ROW(A2:A8)-ROW(A1)),ROW(A2:A8)-ROW(A1))),"")
```

and this into `E2:E8`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A8,SMALL(IF(1-B2:B8,ROW(A2:A8)-ROW(A1)),ROW(A2:A8)-ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]

**Explanation**

This is how Excel will calculate the first formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A8,SMALL(IF(B2:B8,ROW(A2:A8)-ROW(A1)),ROW(A2:A8)-ROW(A1))),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A8,SMALL(IF({1;0;1;0;0;0;1},{2;3;4;5;6;7;8}-1),{2;3;4;5;6;7;8}-1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A8,SMALL(IF({1;0;1;0;0;0;1},{1;2;3;4;5;6;7}),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7})),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A8,SMALL({1;FALSE;3;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;7},{1;2;3;4;5;6;7})),"")
```

Since the second argument of `SMALL` is an array, it will find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. value, ignoring `FALSE` (it will return `#NUM!` for the 4th through 7th value).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A8,{1;3;7;#NUM!;#NUM!;#NUM!;#NUM!}),"")
=IFERROR({"A";"C";"G";#NUM!;#NUM!;#NUM!;#NUM!},"")
={"A";"C";"G";"";"";"";""}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, to help me understand would you be so kind as to explain what each stage is looking for

Comment: When I copy the formula into each cell all i get is the same Customer in each cell i copy the formula into, do i need to change any cell values

Comment: When you use array formulas, you get an array out. Select the entire output range, enter the formula, then ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: @RyanGray I added an explanation at the bottom of my answer.